# Background image at the right bottom corner?

Tags: android, android-layout, background

I have the following simple layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_app_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_description" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

How could I add there background image at the right bottom corner (it should be semi-transparent, since may be behind the text - I've tried to use ImageView, but it doesn't work with such scenario)?

Comment: Why would you say that `ImageView` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/xxx"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:src="@drawable/xxx"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_app_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_description" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This should work! I got the same solution, but you were faster than me :D

Comment: @Thanks, Szymon. Is there any way to avoid usage of `paddingBottom` and `paddingRight` from the parent `RelativeLayout` for this image?

Comment: Not sure if there is. Is there a problem with that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [`XML Bitmap`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#XmlBitmap) drawable as a background. Say the image (with desired transparency) is stored in `bg.png`. If you just use it as the background, it will stretch to fill the view; however, you can define an XML bitmap drawable with a `gravity` attribute. Let's put it in `/res/drawable/bottom_right_bg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bg"
    android:gravity="bottom|right" />
```

Then you can add an `android:background` attribute to the `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_right_bg"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_app_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_description" />
</RelativeLayout>
```